# How to empty a folder in a command prompt? (Windows7)

Tags: windows-7

Need to empty a folder in Windows 7 from the command prompt or batch file. This means deleting all the files and all sub folders and leaving the empty folder.
`del /s /q` leaves empty subfolders so this solution doesn't work for me. I don't want to delete and recreate the folder either.

Comment: Can you exlpain why there is the condition to *not* delete/recreate the folder? Otherwise rmdir /s /q %dir followed by mkdir %dir is the trivial solution.

Comment: @Mike: I'm guessing, timestamps.

Comment: Because there might be files in use and the folder won't get deleted. Then I have to add more code to create the folder only if it doesn't exist. There's a command to cleanly empty a folder. I don't remember it.

Comment: Also, permissions and other metadata. For example, how would you empty the TEMP directory? You wouldn't delete and re-create that, would you? 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) (Secure delete) command to clean a folder.

```
sdelete -s *
```

from with in said folder to clear all of the contents.

Comment: Works good although I had to use the p option because it still left an empty folder.

Comment: Odd as -p 1 is the default.

Answer (score 6):

This command will empty the content of the current folder:

```
rmdir . /s /q
```

The only drawback is that there will be an error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process.

This could be avoided by adding a 2>nul at the end of the command:

```
rmdir . /s /q 2>nul
```

Comment: This is probably the most practical solution to recreating the old `deltree` command to wipe the contents of a folder but not the folder itself. By running it from **within** the target folder, it create an open handle that prevents it from being deleted, and is a single, easy command instead of running multiple operations. It should generally be reliable, as long as it's run from within the folder, it shouldn't mess up. This way, you keep permissions and other metadata intact. 

Answer (score 2):

Try the RMDIR (or aka the RD) command.

> RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
>              in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
>              tree.
>
> /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S

Comment: I think the OPs issue is that he wants to only delete the contained directories and files, while keeping the top level directory. RD does not support wildcards like DEL does.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file:

```
for /D %%p IN (*) do rmdir /S /Q %%p
for %%p in (*) do del %%p
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following commands:

It will delete the whole folder:

```
rmdir /s /q C:\FolderName\
```

It will create the empty folder:

```
mkdir  C:\FolderName\
```

Comment: OP said: " I don't want to delete and recreate the folder either."

Comment: Recreating the folder wipes out all metadata from timestamps to permissions. That might been okay in DOS, but not in the past 20+ years.